# Drupal 8: Using custom date field in View / Filter criteria

Tags: sorting, date, drupal, filter

I have "Content type" called Banner, it has two date fields:

```
ad_start
```

and

```
ad_stop
```

Both set to be date and time format. With ad_start default to "now" and ad_stop default set to "+7 days".

I then have a view "Frontpage Floor Banner" in which I want to have a filter in order to filter out all banners with

```
ad_start => "now"
```

and

```
ab_stop <= "now"
```

Under Configure filter criterion: Content: Start (field_ad_start), Operator has following possible options to choose from:

```
Is equal to
Is not equal to
Contains
Contains any word
Contains all words
Starts with
Does not start with
Ends with
Does not end with
Does not contain
Length is shorter than
Length is longer than
Regular expression
Is empty (NULL)
Is not empty (NOT NULL)
```

However I cant understand which Operator I can use to achieve this...

This is on 8.0.0-beta9.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the latest version of Drupal 8, because for a while there was no Datetime field filter for views, and it would have treated it like an integer rather than a date. In Drupal 8.0.5 (the latest as of this writing) the available operators for a core Datetime field are;

Is less than
Is less than or equal to
Is equal to
Is not equal to
Is greater than or equal to
Is greater than
Is between
Is not between
Regular expression
Is empty (NULL)
Is not empty (NOT NULL)

So for ad_start you would choose 'Is greater than or equal to' and for "Value type" choose 'An offset from the current time such as "+1 day" or "-2 hours -30 minutes"', then enter:

```
now
```

For ad_stop choose 'Is less than or equal to' and for "Value type" choose 'An offset from the current time such as "+1 day" or "-2 hours -30 minutes"', then enter:

```
now
```

[image: view datetime field filter example]
[view datetime field filter example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUHjN.png)

Note that the Date module is not yet available for Drupal 8, but D8 does have a (somewhat limited) core Datetime field, which is what I assume you are using.

Comment: @Caper Voogt , the conditions which you mentioned above are wrong.

Comment: Well, it's been over a year and Drupal 8 has changed fast, so yes, it probably is wrong by now.

Comment: We have now the https://www.drupal.org/project/time_range, which provides a much better UI for time input. When  filtering  in views,  the approach in answer works great

Answer (score -1):

Make sure yo enable the Date Views (date_views) module.

Comment: There is no [date_views](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_views) module.